# When referring to a JSONObject in javascript, how do I refer to it using a variable (rather than the name itself)?

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

I looked up all the other StackOverflow posts for this, but none seemed to work. I'll post my code below:

```
$.getJSON('bugs.json', function (data) {
    for ( var observer = 1; observer <= data.numObservers; observer++) {
        var observerName = "num" + observer;

        var specs = ['congestion', 'bloodflow'];
        for ( var spec in specs) {
            var tableCode = "<br><table id=\"" + observer + specs[spec] + "\" > <thead> <tr> <th>" + specs[spec] + "</th> <th id=\"value\">Value</th> <th id=\"time\">Time</th></tr>";
            $('body').append(tableCode);
            var observerObj = data[observerName] + " kaka " + data.num1.congestion.values[1];

            var selectedSpec = specs[spec];
            for (var i = 0; i < observerObj[selectedSpec].values.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append ("<td> Name </td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[observerName][spec].values[i] + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[observerName][spec].times[i] + "</td>");
                $('#'+observer+spec).append(tr);                
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When using the browser console log, I get an error that `observerObj[selectedSpec]` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit**: the exact console error is:

`TypeError: observerObj[selectedSpec] is undefined`

Comment: Never seen that error message before ; ). What you mean with "does not work"? You've said it twice...

Comment: haha, my bad, the exact error is:

TypeError: observerObj[selectedSpec] is undefined

Comment: can you post the JSON

Comment: I unfortunately cannot because it's slightly confidential information, but I am sure that it is properly formatted and whatnot. I did some trials trying to retrieve data manually and it worked fine.

Comment: As you might be able to see, it is a somewhat complicated JSON with numerous objects within objects and a JSONArray at the deepest level.

Comment: var observerObj = data[observerName] + ..... Its a normal variable not an object

Comment: My mistake again, ignore the stuff after the + "k...
I didn't copy the most recent version.

Comment: @user3773039 If you can't share the JSON, can you at least post `Object.keys(data)`? (Based on your code, I would expect it to be an array of strings like `["num1", "num2", ...]`.) Or, even better, produce a non-confidential example that reproduces the problem that you can share in full.

Comment: `I unfortunately cannot because it's slightly confidential information.` That is a non sequitur. **Reproduce the problem with non-confidential data.** It is not enough for us to "just take your word for it".

Comment: just replace everything inside with a random number and all the strings with a random string, if it still happens yay, if it doesn't then that makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
var observerObj = data[observerName] + " kaka " + data.num1.congestion.values[1];
```

If I am reading this correctly, observerObj is a string - not an array or object.  So observerObj[selectedSpec] would not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over an array as an object.

```
var specs = ['congestion', 'bloodflow'];
for ( var spec in specs) {
```

This is trying to iterate for every `property` on `specs` not each object inside of it. You want to do something like this...

```
var specs = ['congestion', 'bloodflow'];
for ( var i = 0; i < specs.length; i++) {
```

Then access each item via `specs[i]`

Hope this helps!

[MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) about `for ... in` should help too.

Comment: now I get this error: TypeError: observerObj[specs[i]].values is undefined

Comment: @user3773039 I think HarmonicApps answer now applies. You're concatenating strings to make `observerObj` so it's going to be a string, and probably not have the property you're looking for. What are you trying to do with `observerObj`?